# How to place an image at the right of a centered one

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to put an image next to a centered one

the code looks like this :

```
<div id="body3" >
    <center><img  HEIGHT="700" WIDTH="600" src="Logo.jpg"></center>
    <img height="40" width="220" ;" src="reserver.png" style="float: right;">
</div>
```

but the second image will go underneath the first one and to the right.I want it to be to the right of the centered one.

Any options? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id="body3" >
    <center><img  HEIGHT="700" WIDTH="600" style="display: inline-block;" src="Logo.jpg">  <img height="40" width="220" style="display: inline-block;" src="reserver.png">  </center>

</div>
```

Comment: So I tried your option and it doesn't work. The only css I have other than the one I'm using in the <img> is a background color in my css sheet.

Comment: I edited my answer.  Put both images inside the center tag.

Comment: Allright so that fixes that issue but that means that the originally centered image is a little bit on the left from the centre...

Comment: You can either add a left margin to the first image or look down at derekcbaldwin's answer.  You'll be adding a left margin either way, but derekcbaldwin's answer is more in keeping with industry best practices

Comment: and the center tag wins!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question you want the minor box being aligned at after the big box and to the right? And don't want to "expand" the major box width. If is this your question, here's your solution:

1- Treat your #body3 as a wrapper to avoid your div quit the desired position.

2- Align your elements with `margin: 0 auto;` or `text-align:center;`

CSS

```
 img:nth-of-type(1){
        margin:0 auto;
        background:red;

    }
     img:nth-of-type(2){
        float:right;
    }

    #body3{
       margin:0 auto;
       width:600px;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="body3" >

    <img height="700" width="600" src="http://placehold.it/600x700">
     <img height="40" width="220" src="http://placehold.it/220x40">

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fvcee05a/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can use css floats.

see example at https://jsfiddle.net/z3kwx1x5/1/

Learn more at https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

```
<div id="body3" style="width:1200px;">
    <img style="float:left;margin-left: 220px;" height="700" width="600" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
    <img style="float:left;margin-top:330px;" height="40" width="220" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png">
</div>
```

Both images are floated left. If you want the first image to be centered, you can add `margin-left` to the inline style attribute. The value of the margin-left would depend on the width of the div#body3

Comment: Downvote didn't come from me but seems like you're using floats for the sake of floats.  Floating the first image left requires OP to do extra work just to get the image back to center, which he/she already has.  Basically one step backward and then 2 forward.  You're strategy has merit but OP didn't ask for a new strategy, he asked how to place the second image to the right of the first image, which is already centered.

Comment: Gotcha. I don't really support using deprecated tags though... http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_center.asp. I suppose you could always use tables or absolute positioning, but that is just gross.

Comment: I really don't want to use absolute positioning but I srsly can't figure this one out...

Comment: I would say you have 3 options: 1. use divs and floats 2. use tables 3. use absolute positioning